# Could monitors in general work in lesser resolutions than officially supported?

Tags: display, resolution

For example this Iiyama 25" ProLite E2591HSU-B1 monitor is 16:9 format, but the only resolution of same format it officially supports is 1920*1080.

Could it work in 1280*720 mode?
This is user manual for this monitor: https://cdn.iiyama.com/f/14d391a166ad6fb9e7fb3a9c48be88a9_b-e2591hsu-usermanual-e-reva.pdf

And the last page has this table:
[image]

The only single 16:9 resolution there is the last one... but I need lower.

Comment: Yes, but in case of LCD you will have blurry image

Comment: @user996142 it is not guaranteed to work. Did you read somewhere this resolution is going to work, or have you tried it yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the manual does not list the resolution, the chance is high that it will not work, or not work as expected.

It would not be the first time I try a resolution that is not in the manual, and that it works. But it also not the first time when I think a resolution should work even though it is not in the manual, because it is a very standard resolution, only to find out that it doesn't work.

That said, keep in mind that when you go to a resolution that is not the native resolution, the image quality will always degrade because it has to perform scaling from an arbitrary resolution to the native one, so the image becomes blurry.

If you want to use a smaller resolution in Windows, then use the native resolution and increase the DPI to make everything bigger.

If you run an application that specifically needs this resolution, contact the developer of the application and ask for 1080p support.